# WordPress File URL Path Incorrect

Tags: urls, uploads

I have images uploaded to a WordPress site and they can be accessed by the following URL:

`http:/eatdrink.ca/content/uploads/2014/09/FoodWebSummer-main-420x194.jpg`

but WordPress is giving the following URL:

`http://eatdrink.ca/wp/http:/eatdrink.ca/content/uploads/2014/09/FoodWebSummer-main-420x194.jpg`

Why is that extra `http://eatdrink.ca/wp/` being thrown on at the beginning? It shows this file URL on the edit media screen and from the front end, so no images are showing, meanwhile they are there.

The path in the database shows the correct image path and the GUID of the media post is also the correct one:

`http:/eatdrink.ca/content/uploads/2014/09/FoodWebSummer-main-420x194.jpg`

How does WordPress generate the File URL? I could not find that value in the database, so I assume WordPress handles generating it in code.

It seems to be throwing the WordPress Address (From General Settings) in front of the image path.

Does anyone know why WordPress would be doing this?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with a particular image uploading plugin where it was prepending the base URL to a value that already had the full URL. Are you using any plugins that are related to uploading this image?

Answer (score 1):

Because you only have one slash instead of two in your URL:

http:/eatdrink.ca

That double slash ain't just for looks. :)

Go to the hidden options.php page located at /wp-admin/options.php. Check and see what the "upload_url_path" is set to. Make sure it has a double slash there (if it's empty, that is acceptable as well, don't change it away from being empty). Don't change anything else while you're here.

Also check the URL's on the Settings->General page. Make sure they have the proper number of slashes as well.

Comment: For some reason the double slash didn't get copied.. it is there when I look now: http://eatdrink.ca/wp/http://eatdrink.ca/content/uploads/2014/08/ED49-cookbook-banner.jpg But it is still throwing the wp address in front of the image url

Comment: What is the upload_url_path set to?

Comment: It is blank in the database.